# Compare a SQL table column names with another table column data for missing columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a query that will look in one table (A) at all the column names, and then compare those names against another table (B), but in table B I need to compare them with actual text values.  Not the most clear explanation so hopefully this example demonstrates what I need a bit better.

So `TableA` has columns such as `Date, DiabetesA, DiabetesB, DiabetesC,...`

`TableB` has one column named `VarName` and inside that column will be all the column names from other tables (such as A).

I need to make a query that will check the columns of tableA and make sure those column names exist in tableB's `Varname`.

I know how to check if columns exist in both tables, but I do not know how to check if a value appears in another table.

So it'll look something like:

```
Select DiabetesA,DiabetesB,DiabetesC from Table A
```

and then I want to compare that against

```
Select VarName from Table B
```

and inside Varname should be all the column names from other tables.  I need to track down the ones that don't exist in Varname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**

We use `sys.tables` to get the correct `object_id` of the `tableA` and use that to get all column names from `Sys.columns` which is then used to check names with `TableB`

**query**

```
--create table tableA(DiabetesA varchar(10),DiabetesB varchar(10),DiabetesC varchar(10))
--create table tableB(varname varchar(10))
--insert into tableB values ('DiabetesA')

select c.name from sys.columns c inner join sys.tables t on c.object_id=t.object_id and t.type='U' 
and t.name ='tableA '
left join tableB B on B.varname=C.name
where B.varname is NULL
```

**[Working SQL demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/879dc/1)**

**See my results below**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  Using SQL Objects is new to me so this helps me understand it much better.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code to find columns that are not found in B

```
select name 
from sys.columns 
where object_id = object_id('A')
   and name not in (select VarName from B)
```